# Call.cancel() behavior clarification

Tags: okhttp

Currently in okhttp 3.10.0, if we execute the following code:

```
for (Call call : getOkHttpClient().dispatcher().runningCalls()) {
    if (call.request().tag().equals(tag)) {
        call.cancel();
    }
}
```

The real connection (socket) will be closed, is there a way to just drop the call without closing the underlying connection (socket)? So that the underlying connection (socket) could be reused by the future requests to the same server.

The purpose of this cancellation is merely to save some bandwidth while still being able to reuse the connection and avoid re-establishing the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The socket is not closed for HTTP/2 connections. HTTP/1.1 lacks a mechanism to cancel a call without losing the connection.